# Any workaround to enter captcha using automation script?

Tags: selenium, protractor, captcha

I am trying to write an automation script using protractor wherein, I have to fill the registration form, enter the captcha and submit the form. I am facing issues while handling the captcha part.

I know that captcha is made so as to avoid robot intervention. But, in order to proceed further, I anyhow have to automate that part. It would be great if I could get some workaround with it. Either of selenium, protractor scripts would work for me.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: No , I think what you can do is sleep your script for a white , enter captcha and continue script.

Comment: @HelpingHands - Please guide me on that.

Comment: in your script add `Thread.sleep(5000)` ,and enter captcha manually and  script will continue.

Comment: @HelpingHands - It really worked. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Yep , Let me put that as answer so it will help to other users.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I know there is no way for that , what you can do is , Tell your script to idle for a while until you enter captcha manually.

So you can do like , use `Thread.sleep(5000)` when your script reach at captcha field , then enter captcha manually in 5 seconds and your script will resume. According to me this is good way to manage captcha during automation.